# Import Module.bas from http/ftp?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I want to import a module via ftp/http.

For example:
ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Import ("http://www.server.de/modul.bas")

I would like to save the code of a module in a central file, but we don't have a shared drive. So I would like to upload my code to some Server and update it from time to time.

Comment: Download the file to a local temp folder and import it from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on Tim's comment.  Download it to the temp folder and import it from there.  You can download a file using the code below.

```
Need reference to Microsoft Internet Controls
'Example
'myURL = "http://www.server.de/modul.bas"
'savePath = Environ("temp")
'fileName = "modul.bas"
Sub SaveInternetFile(myURL As String, savePath As String, fileName As String)
    Dim WinHttpReq As Object
    'create XMLHttp object
    Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False
    'send request
    WinHttpReq.send
    'check the status to make sure we succeeded
    If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
        Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        oStream.Open
        oStream.Type = 1
        oStream.Write WinHttpReq.responseBody
        oStream.SaveToFile (savePath & fileName)
        oStream.Close   
    'import the new file
    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Import(savePath & filename) 
    End If 
End Sub
```